# Any Python package that can help get list of installed updates in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I want to know if there is a package already available in Python that can help me get a list of already installed updates on a Windows machines. By installed updates I mean the Windows update.

Comment: I am sorry about the question not being formatted as it should have been but I dont understand the reason for marking it  negative.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not specify any requirements, subprocess will do:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

res = Popen(['wmic', 'qfe', 'list', 'brief', '/format:texttablewsys'], stdout=PIPE)
output = res.communicate()[0]
print output
```

`wmic` is a commandline WMI tool.

And if you do not want to spawn a worker process directly (wmi will do it indirectly anyways), you could take a look at the [WMI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) package.

Comment: A table is good for display, but XML will be more useful to a program: `output = subprocess.check_output('wmic qfe get /format:rawxml')`.